# setuptools dependency-management for different python versions

Tags: python, pip, setuptools, pypi

Assume you have a giant continous integration to care about, there are tons of terabyte of docker-containers, and rebuilding containers takes more time somebody could ever pay for and whatever version you change will break all the depencies.

Conclusion: you have docker-containers with python x.y.z and for all of those I need to install a pypi-package

Therefore I tried something like this:

```
install_requires = [
"jsonschema==2.6.0;python_version<='3.7'",
"jsonschema==4.19.1;python_version>'3.7'",
]
```

but still i get an error in python 3.7.9 (that could be ignored)

```
ERROR: ecuci-github 1.0.19 has requirement jsonschema==4.19.1, but you'll have jsonschema 2.6.0 which is incompatible.
ERROR: ecuci-jgod 1.0.22 has requirement jsonschema==4.19.1, but you'll have jsonschema 2.6.0 which is incompatible.
ERROR: ecuci-checks 1.0.8 has requirement jsonschema==4.19.1, but you'll have jsonschema 2.6.0 which is incompatible.
ERROR: ecuci-release-gui 1.0.75 has requirement jsonschema==4.19.1, but you'll have jsonschema 2.6.0 which is incompatible.
ERROR: ecuci-packaging 1.1.79 has requirement jsonschema==4.19.1, but you'll have jsonschema 2.6.0 which is incompatible.
Installing collected packages: ecuci-certs, ecuci-release, typing-extensions, annotated-types, pydantic-core, pydantic, peppercorn, ecuci-varparser, ecuci-buildgen, pywin32, packaging, urllib3, idna, certifi, charset-normalizer, requests, websocket-client, docker, jsonschema, appdirs, cached-property, lxml, pytz, six, isodate, defusedxml, requests-toolbelt, zipp, importlib-metadata, attrs, zeep, ecuci-github, ecuci-jgod, ecuci-flexcopy, ecuci-choco, ecuci-checks, ecuci-security, ecuci-engine, pycparser, cffi, cryptography, pyspnego, requests-ntlm, ecuci-flexclean, ecuci-release-gui, ecuci-quatelets, ecuci-validation, ecuci-packaging, ecuci-conan-install, ecuci-tools
Successfully installed annotated-types-0.5.0 appdirs-1.4.4 attrs-23.1.0 cached-property-1.5.2 certifi-2023.11.17 cffi-1.15.1 charset-normalizer-3.3.2 cryptography-41.0.7 defusedxml-0.7.1 docker-6.1.3 ecuci-buildgen-1.0.102 ecuci-certs-1.0.4 ecuci-checks-1.0.8 ecuci-choco-1.0.21 ecuci-conan-install-1.0.14 ecuci-engine-1.0.32 ecuci-flexclean-1.0.6 ecuci-flexcopy-1.0.6 ecuci-github-1.0.19 ecuci-jgod-1.0.22 ecuci-packaging-1.1.79 ecuci-quatelets-1.0.9 ecuci-release-1.0.26 ecuci-release-gui-1.0.75 ecuci-security-1.0.18 ecuci-tools-1.1.480 ecuci-validation-1.0.19 ecuci-varparser-1.0.22 idna-3.6 importlib-metadata-6.7.0 isodate-0.6.1 jsonschema-2.6.0 lxml-4.9.3 packaging-23.2 peppercorn-0.6 pycparser-2.21 pydantic-2.3.0 pydantic-core-2.6.3 pyspnego-0.9.2 pytz-2023.3.post1 pywin32-306 requests-2.30.0 requests-ntlm-1.2.0 requests-toolbelt-1.0.0 six-1.16.0 typing-extensions-4.7.1 urllib3-1.26.15 websocket-client-1.6.1 zeep-3.4.0 zipp-3.15.0
WARNING: You are using pip version 20.1.1; however, version 23.3.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'C:\Data\ecuci\pyenv37\Scripts\python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.

(pyenv37) C:\Data\ecuci>echo %errorlevel%
0
```

while its fine in version 3.10

So question is: how to get rid of those errors, I considered following webpages:
https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/quickstart.html
https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/issues/3313